# How to reassign numeric order to df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with a logical index like

```
1, 32.2, 23324.32, 23.2
2, 72.4, 32.12, 623.5
    .     .     .
500, 34.7, 24.3, 43.9
```

When I create a new df based on certain filters from the original df, I have a new df with values, for example, like:

```
1, 32.2, 23324.32, 23.2
9, 2.4, 34.4, 63.0
48, 0.7, 24.3, 43.8
77, 8.7, 24.3, 73.9
    .     .     .
```

How can I reassign the index col of the new df to be like this?

```
1, 32.2, 23324.32, 23.2
2, 2.4, 34.4, 63.0
3, 0.7, 24.3, 43.8
4, 8.7, 24.3, 73.9
    .     .     .
```

Comment: [df.reset_index(drop=True)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) just try to do it on a copy of the frame and not a slice.

Comment: Not sure if OP wants this, but `df.reset_index(drop=True)` will make an index starting from 0. OP has their desired index starting from 1.

Comment: @jakub Good point. Then the OP can just add `.index+1` and assign it. `new.index = new.reset_index(drop=True).index+1`

Comment: @It_is_Chris hi, can you answer with your comment so I can mark as solved? thanks!